# Getting connection refused while executing scp connection in amazon ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I want to copy my file from local machine to remote machine in amazon ec2. I am executing following command:

```
 scp -i ilmkey.pem shahjahan.txt ubuntu@ec2-52-25-74-139.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:~
```

I am getting following error:

> ssh: connect to host ec2-52-25-74-139.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
>   port 22: Connection refused lost connection

The command `telnet HOSTNAME 22` gives:

> telnet: could not resolve HOSTNAME/22: Name or service not known

I have set

> SSH TCP 22
>   0.0.0.0/0

in security group tab. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Did you just start this instance?

Comment: Also, I must say, SO isn't the perfect place for a question like this, as it doesn't relate to programming. You might want to try on [ServerFault](https://www.serverfault.com/).

Comment: @Will Yeah, I started.

Comment: how about `telnet ec2-52-25-74-139.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com 22`, what you get?

Answer (score 0):

A "connection refused" error makes me think that `sshd` is not running or that the machine failed to boot. If the Security Group was rejecting you, the question would time out instead. If this instance was already running and SSH was working before, reboot the machine from the console and see if SSH comes back up when it reboots. Also look at the logs via the AWS console, and if you still can't get anywhere, contact AWS Support.